# How to build a regression model in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regression, data-fitting

I want to build a regression model for a data set, already know that :

`x_1` and `y` is quadratic relationship, `x_2` and `y` is linear; but not sure whether `x_2` has quadratic relationship with `y`, nor if `x_1` and `x_2` has some sort of interaction.

```
x_1: ['66.29', '40.96', '73.00', '45.01', '57.20', '26.85', '38.12', '35.84', '75.80', '37.41', '54.38', '46.19', '46.13', '30.37', '39.06', '79.38', '52.77', '55.92']
x_2: ['7.00', '5.00', '10.00', '6.00', '4.00', '5.00', '4.00', '6.00', '9.00', '5.00', '2.00', '7.00', '4.00', '3.00', '5.00', '1.00', '8.00', '6.00'] 
y: ['196.00', '63.00', '252.00', '84.00', '126.00', '14.00', '49.00', '49.00', '266.00', '49.00', '105.00', '98.00', '77.00', '14.00', '56.00', '245.00', '133.00', '133.00']
```

So I constructed that function:[image: SampleFunction]

But I don't know how to evaluate it, I tried `curve_fit` in `scipy`, yet seems it does not work for multiple independent variables. So is there a way to do that in python?

Comment: Why not using function from ML lib like http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html ? Is it important that you implement everything yourself ? If yes then you should check upon `Cost Function` and `Optimizer` using this function to find out your best parameters like `Gradient Descent`

Comment: @MathiasDesch Well, figure out the way to get coefficients, but seems there's no way to evaluate confidence interval in sklearn , is it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sckit-learn package in python includes both linear and polynomial regression models. Have a look at the link : [linear and polynomial regression models](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html).

Basically, `y = c1 + c2 * x1 + c3 * x2 + c4 * x1^2 + c5 * x2^2 + c6 * x1 * x2` 
can be transformed by defining new variable `z = [x1, x2, x1^2, x2^2, x1*x2]`.

With this transformation, the equation can be rewritten as

`y = c1 + c2 z1 + c3 * z2 + c4 * z3 + c5 * z4 + c6 * z5`.

Thus, the problem of polynomial fitting has now been reduced to linear one and the linear model trained on polynomial features is able to exactly recover the input polynomial coefficients.

You can find several examples of polynomial regression in the link above.